# auto squencentially rename files based on last, numbered, file in folder and move to that location

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am looking for suggestions on how to automatically monitor a folder for uploads (pictures only) and move them into another with a specific filename "MyLife" in the prefix and a numbering sequence in the suffix. I store all my pictures in \Documents\Photos\MyLife and they are numbered with digits i.e. MyLife5523.jpg I would like to monitor a folder \Documents\picsupload for images and have a script or program to check \Documents\Photos\MyLife for the last existing file name (number) and rename the image to the next sequential number and move to \Documents\Photos\MyLife

i.e.

\Documents\picsupload has IMG_20170313_123003.jpg, IMG_20170318_123003.jpg, and IMG_20170313_123030.jpg

The program/script checks \Documents\Photos\MyLife and finds the last file is MyLife5523.jpg

IMG_20170313_123003.jpg, IMG_20170318_123003.jpg, and IMG_20170313_123030.jpg are renamed to MyLife5524.jpg, MyLife5525.jpg, and MyLife5526.jpg and moved to \Documents\Photos\MyLife

I currently have AutoHotKey and DropIt installed. However, I'm open to other suggestions.

Respectfully,

JA

Answer (score 0):

Use [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to poll the source directory for files using [Loop, FilePattern](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm). When found, use [FileMove](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileMove.htm) to move and rename them into your destination folder. Use [IniWrite](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm) and [IniRead](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm) to save numeric suffix so you don't have to scan the destination folder every time.

Comment: A trade-off between performance and coding effort/reliability would be to only scan the destination folder once on program start, and then keeping the current index in a variable.

Comment: I'll give it a try and post the script to share. Thank you.